# Laravel app:name broke my entire application

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3

I have recently deployed my application and wanted to change my app's name afterwards, so I have done it once and changed it to RbxRock.

Then I realized that I made a spelling and therefore I changed it back to Laravel, but at this point, I'm now getting a lot of errors and exceptions that I can't even use `php artisan` any more.

One of which is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist in /var/www/html/rocks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:749
```

Here's my `composer.json` file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "devdojo/chatter": "^0.1.22",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^2.6",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
        "paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php":"v3.6.106",
        "laravel-notification-channels/discord": "^0.0.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
        "fahim/laravel5-paypal-ipn": "dev-master@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "ePOS\\": "app/ePOS"
        },"files": [
            "app/Library/paypalHelpers.php",
            "app/Library/robloxHelpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

In the top of of Kernel.php

```
namespace App\Console;

//use DB;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
}
```

.

Comment: Track down the file in the error you mentioned.  At the very top of the file, what is the namespace?  Also, make sure to "composer dumpautoload".

Comment: @MMMTroy I did do dump-autoload a lot of times, nothing helps

Comment: Have you looked over your .env file at all?  I've read that having a whitespace in a wrong spot can result in this error.  Are you doing any caching, such as config:cache?  If so, try and clear that.  Lastly, try and "rm bootstrap/cache/compiled.php" and then "composer update".

Comment: @MMMTroy I am doing caching but its only view caching, not config caching

Comment: and I do not have compiled.php in my cache directory ;(